# ee: redirect url with trailing forward slash

Tags: redirect, expressionengine

How can I redirect to the correct page if somebody adds a trailing forward slash to a url in expression engine?

For example:
A) www.acme.com/event - is the correct url

B) www.acme.com/event/ - has the same content

The problem is I'm using Disqus as a commenting system and it interprets both as different pages. So the simple solution is to redirect to url A when the trailing slash appears.

```
{if segment_2=="event/"}
 {redirect="/event"}
{/if}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas that don't involve .htaccess? It's only for one page.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the URL doesn't matter.  It's the value of `disqus_url` that uniquely identifies that page. You should be able to set that relably.   https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables

Comment: Great call! You are absolutely correct. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting my comment as an answer...

Looks like the URL doesn't matter. It's the value of `disqus_url` that uniquely identifies that page. You should be able to set that reliably.

From the [documentation](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables)...

> disqus_url
>
> Tells the Disqus service the URL of the current page. If undefined,
>   Disqus will take the window.location.href. This URL is used to look up
>   or create a thread if disqus_identifier is undefined. In addition,
>   this URL is always saved when a thread is being created so that Disqus
>   knows what page a thread belongs to.
>
> While the window.location.href is used in absence of disqus_url, we
>   highly recommend defining this variable. If a user visits your page at
>   the URL http://example.com/helloworld.html?123, Disqus may in fact
>   load a different thread than if the user came from
>   http://example.com/helloworld.html.
>
> To make sure the right thread is always displayed, you should define
>   on your page, using an absolute URL, var disqus_url =
>   'http://example.com/helloworld.html';